# NSValidationMissingMandatoryPropertyError - The operation couldn't be completed. (Cocoa error 1570.)

Tags: core-data

I have an error with Core Data :

**{
    NSLocalizedDescription = "The operation couldn\U2019t be completed. (Cocoa error 1570.)";
    NSValidationErrorKey = CorbeilleItem;
    NSValidationErrorObject = " (entity: ACSheetList; id: 0xde22cd0  ; data: {\n    Actions = \"\";\n    CorbeilleItem = nil;\n    Sections = \"\";\n    idDoc = 0;\n    title = nil;\n})";
}**

My Data Model is next :

- http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/214/xcode2.png/
- http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/705/xcode.png/

And my source code is :

```
        ACSheetList *newSheet = (ACSheetList*)[NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"ACSheetList" inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];

        @try {

            if ([item isFault] == YES) {
                NSLog(@"CorbeilleItem is fault");
            }

            if ([item isDeleted] == YES) {
                NSLog(@"CorbeilleItem is deleted");
            }

            [newSheet setIdDoc:documentIdTemp];
            [newSheet setTitle:@"title 0"];

            [newSheet setCorbeilleItem:item];
            [item setSheet:newSheet];
        }
        @catch (NSException *exception) {
            [self addTrace:ERROR description:exception.reason];
            NSLog(@"%@", [exception userInfo]);
        }
```

Could you help me, please?

Answer (score 0):

I am facing the same issue, with scalar values of the core-data object while migrating. 
try using KVC to set values ie. use

```
[newSheet setValue:item forKey:@"corbeilleItem"];
```

instead of

```
[newSheet setCorbeilleItem:item];
```

It worked for me.